# How to Auto scale workers in AWS step functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

We are implementing a process using AWS step functions. Some of the tasks in this process take long time. We are using Activities(workers) running in ECS instances for this step. The state machine is like this:

> Trigger -> step 1 (Lambda) -> step2 (ECS) -> final step

Is there a way to find the number of tasks in queue waiting to be picked up by the step2 workers and use this information  to auto scale the workers (ECS cluster)?

Comment: Have you tried to research this elsewhere? Questions here generally need to show some research initiative.

Comment: You may also want to look at the CloudWatch metrics for activities, specifically `ActivityScheduleTime`. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/sfn-metricscollected.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the api `list_executions` to get the list of **running** executions and
than for each of this executions call `get_execution_history`.

In the response you can iterate the execution events. 
If you find in the list `ActivityScheduled` and you don't see `ActivityStarted` it means it is waiting for a worker to take this task.

Answer (score 0):

I found [here](https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2019/06/autoscaling-aws-step-functions-activities.html) a very nice use case and for Step Function autoscaling.

I'm going to use some of those insights, such as using cloudwatch alarms to set get the current state (i.e. scale-up /scale-down decisions); using SQS to hold the alarms etc.